# How to pass a controller's Id to SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr

I am trying to create a real-time chat with a database. Without SignalR it works as it's supposed to. However, I want to add real-time functionality. The application queries the database for the `MessageId`, and then it lists all the messages with the `MessageId`. I passed the `MessageId` as a parameter into the url. and use that to look through the database, e.g. `sever:messages/open/{MessageId}`. But signalR is not getting to the controller's Id. if I just have `_FC.UserMessage.ToList();` without any parameters, it works fine. I just need to know how can i use it with the controller's parameter.

Update: I just did more test and when i take away the variables in the site.js file, i.e. `${v.Date}`, `${v.Message}` the messages appear. However, only three appear from one account appear. So this is a real head-scratcher. It seems like the way I'm naming the variables is wrong since it throws me an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Date')` error. And now the problem with only displaying three messages. Now I'm thinking it has nothing to do with the controller parameters, but the naming of the variables. I thought I could name it `v.UM.Date` since `public IEnumerable<UserMessageModel> UM {get; set;}` is the name of the variable I have in the `UserMessagesObj.cs` view model. But that's throwing me the same error.

MessagesController:

```
using Flubr.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Flubr.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Flubr.Controllers
{
    public class MessagesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly FlubrContext _FC;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _UM;
        private readonly IHubContext<SignalHub> _signal;

        public MessagesController(FlubrContext FC, UserManager<ApplicationUser> UM, IHubContext<SignalHub> signal)
        {
            _FC = FC;
            _UM = UM;
            _signal = signal;

        }
        

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetOpen(string id, UserMessagesObj umo)
        {

            var message = _FC.UserMessage.Include("applicationUser").Where(o => o.MessageId == id).Where(o => o.Message != "").ToList();

            umo.UM = message;

            return View(umo);
        }
        public IActionResult Open(string id, UserMessagesObj umo)
        {

            var message = _FC.UserMessage.Include("applicationUser").Where(o => o.MessageId == id).Where(o => o.Message != "").ToList();

            umo.UM = message;
            
            return View(umo);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Open(string id, UserMessagesModel um, UserMessagesObj umo)
        {

            var message = _FC.UserMessage.Include("applicationUser").Where(o => o.MessageId == id).Where(o => o.Message != "").ToList();
            Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

            umo.UM = message;
            umo.UM2.UserMessageId = g;
            umo.UM2.Id = _UM.GetUserAsync(User).Result.Id;
            umo.UM2.MessageId = id;
            umo.UM2.Date = DateTime.Now;
            _FC.UserMessage.Add(umo.UM2);
            await _FC.SaveChangesAsync();
            await _signal.Clients.All.SendAsync("LoadData");

            return View(umo);
        }
    }
}
```

Open.cshtml

```
@model UserMessagesObj
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Flubr.Areas.Identity.Data

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar.css">




    <style>
        * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #abd9e9;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#container {
    width: 750px;
    height: 800px;
    background: #eff3f7;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
    width: 260px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #3b3e49;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

main {
    width: 490px;
    height: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

aside header {
    padding: 30px 20px;
}

aside input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 20px;
    background-color: #5e616a;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_search.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 170px;
    background-size: 40px;
}

aside input::placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

aside ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 690px;
}

aside li {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

aside li:hover {
    background-color: #5e616a;
}

h2,
h3 {
    margin: 0;
}

aside li img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

aside li div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

aside li h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

aside li h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7e818a;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.status {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.green {
    background-color: #58b666;
}

.orange {
    background-color: #ff725d;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #6fbced;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

main header {
    height: 110px;
    padding: 30px 20px 30px 40px;
}

main header>* {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

main header img:first-child {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

main header img:last-child {
    width: 24px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

main header div {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 145px;
}

main header h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

main header h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #7e818a;
}

#chat {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 535px;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

#chat li {
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

#chat h2,
#chat h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#chat h3 {
    color: #bbb;
}

#chat .entete {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#chat .message {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 25px;
    max-width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#chat .me {
    text-align: right;
}

#chat .you .message {
    background-color: #58b666;
}

#chat .me .message {
    background-color: #6fbced;
}

#chat .triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#chat .you .triangle {
    border-color: transparent transparent #58b666 transparent;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#chat .me .triangle {
    border-color: transparent transparent #6fbced transparent;
    margin-left: 375px;
}

main footer {
    height: 155px;
    padding: 20px 30px 10px 20px;
}

main footer textarea {
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

main footer textarea::placeholder {
    color: #ddd;
}

main footer img {
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

main footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6fbced;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 333px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
    </style>








</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <aside>
            <header>
                
            </header>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/chat_avatar_01.jpg" alt="">
                    <div>
                        <h2>Prénom Nom</h2>
                        <h3>
                            <span class="status orange"></span>
                            offline
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <main>
            <header>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/chat_avatar_01.jpg" alt="">
                <div>
                    <h2>Chat with </h2>
                    <h3>already 1902 messages</h3>
                </div>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_star.png" alt="">
            </header>
            <ul id="chat"> </ul>
            <footer>
                <form method ="post" asp-controller="Messages" asp-action="Open" >
                    <textarea asp-for="@Model.UM2.Message" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_picture.png" alt="">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_file.png" alt="">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" style="float: right;">Send</button>
                </form>
            </footer>
        </main>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

site.js

```
@model UserMessagesObj
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Flubr.Areas.Identity.Data

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar.css">




    <style>
        * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #abd9e9;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#container {
    width: 750px;
    height: 800px;
    background: #eff3f7;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
    width: 260px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #3b3e49;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

main {
    width: 490px;
    height: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

aside header {
    padding: 30px 20px;
}

aside input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 20px;
    background-color: #5e616a;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_search.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 170px;
    background-size: 40px;
}

aside input::placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

aside ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 690px;
}

aside li {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

aside li:hover {
    background-color: #5e616a;
}

h2,
h3 {
    margin: 0;
}

aside li img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

aside li div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

aside li h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

aside li h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7e818a;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.status {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.green {
    background-color: #58b666;
}

.orange {
    background-color: #ff725d;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #6fbced;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

main header {
    height: 110px;
    padding: 30px 20px 30px 40px;
}

main header>* {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

main header img:first-child {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

main header img:last-child {
    width: 24px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

main header div {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 145px;
}

main header h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

main header h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #7e818a;
}

#chat {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 535px;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

#chat li {
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

#chat h2,
#chat h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#chat h3 {
    color: #bbb;
}

#chat .entete {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#chat .message {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 25px;
    max-width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#chat .me {
    text-align: right;
}

#chat .you .message {
    background-color: #58b666;
}

#chat .me .message {
    background-color: #6fbced;
}

#chat .triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#chat .you .triangle {
    border-color: transparent transparent #58b666 transparent;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#chat .me .triangle {
    border-color: transparent transparent #6fbced transparent;
    margin-left: 375px;
}

main footer {
    height: 155px;
    padding: 20px 30px 10px 20px;
}

main footer textarea {
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

main footer textarea::placeholder {
    color: #ddd;
}

main footer img {
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

main footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6fbced;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 333px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
    </style>








</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <aside>
            <header>
                
            </header>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/chat_avatar_01.jpg" alt="">
                    <div>
                        <h2>Prénom Nom</h2>
                        <h3>
                            <span class="status orange"></span>
                            offline
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <main>
            <header>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/chat_avatar_01.jpg" alt="">
                <div>
                    <h2>Chat with </h2>
                    <h3>already 1902 messages</h3>
                </div>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_star.png" alt="">
            </header>
            <ul id="chat"> </ul>
            <footer>
                <form method ="post" asp-controller="Messages" asp-action="Open" >
                    <textarea asp-for="@Model.UM2.Message" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_picture.png" alt="">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_file.png" alt="">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" style="float: right;">Send</button>
                </form>
            </footer>
        </main>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

SignalHub.cs

```
@model UserMessagesObj
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Flubr.Areas.Identity.Data

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar.css">




    <style>
        * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #abd9e9;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#container {
    width: 750px;
    height: 800px;
    background: #eff3f7;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
    width: 260px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #3b3e49;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

main {
    width: 490px;
    height: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

aside header {
    padding: 30px 20px;
}

aside input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 20px;
    background-color: #5e616a;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_search.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 170px;
    background-size: 40px;
}

aside input::placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

aside ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 690px;
}

aside li {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

aside li:hover {
    background-color: #5e616a;
}

h2,
h3 {
    margin: 0;
}

aside li img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

aside li div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

aside li h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

aside li h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7e818a;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.status {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.green {
    background-color: #58b666;
}

.orange {
    background-color: #ff725d;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #6fbced;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

main header {
    height: 110px;
    padding: 30px 20px 30px 40px;
}

main header>* {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

main header img:first-child {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

main header img:last-child {
    width: 24px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

main header div {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 145px;
}

main header h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

main header h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #7e818a;
}

#chat {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 535px;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

#chat li {
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

#chat h2,
#chat h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#chat h3 {
    color: #bbb;
}

#chat .entete {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#chat .message {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 25px;
    max-width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#chat .me {
    text-align: right;
}

#chat .you .message {
    background-color: #58b666;
}

#chat .me .message {
    background-color: #6fbced;
}

#chat .triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#chat .you .triangle {
    border-color: transparent transparent #58b666 transparent;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#chat .me .triangle {
    border-color: transparent transparent #6fbced transparent;
    margin-left: 375px;
}

main footer {
    height: 155px;
    padding: 20px 30px 10px 20px;
}

main footer textarea {
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

main footer textarea::placeholder {
    color: #ddd;
}

main footer img {
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

main footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6fbced;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 333px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
    </style>








</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <aside>
            <header>
                
            </header>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/chat_avatar_01.jpg" alt="">
                    <div>
                        <h2>Prénom Nom</h2>
                        <h3>
                            <span class="status orange"></span>
                            offline
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <main>
            <header>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/chat_avatar_01.jpg" alt="">
                <div>
                    <h2>Chat with </h2>
                    <h3>already 1902 messages</h3>
                </div>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_star.png" alt="">
            </header>
            <ul id="chat"> </ul>
            <footer>
                <form method ="post" asp-controller="Messages" asp-action="Open" >
                    <textarea asp-for="@Model.UM2.Message" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_picture.png" alt="">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1940306/ico_file.png" alt="">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" style="float: right;">Send</button>
                </form>
            </footer>
        </main>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

StartUp.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Flubr
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o => {

                o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;

            });
            services.AddRazorPages();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapHub<SignalHub>("/SignalHub");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

UserMessagesObj.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Flubr.Models
{
    public class UserMessagesObj
    {
        public IEnumerable<UserMessagesModel> UM { get; set; }
        public UserMessagesModel UM2 { get; set; }
        public MessagesModel MM { get; set; }
    }
}
```